# How to Require a Custom Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm writing a gem that depends on another gem I've created.

In my host gem, I'm requiring my gem as a dependency like this:

```
$:.push File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__) 

Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
  s.require_path = "lib"
  s.files = Dir["lib/**/*"]
  s.test_files = Dir["spec/**/*"] 

  s.add_dependency "my_other_gem"
end
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'my_other_gem' path: '../my_other_gem', require: 'my_other_gem'

gemspec
```

And inside the host gem, I've got a class that requires my_other_gem:

`require 'my_other_gem'`

In my_other_gem, inside `lib/my_other_gem.rb`, I've got two more require classes.  So it looks like this:

```
require 'my_other_gem/foo'
require 'my_other_gem/bar'
```

When I spin up IRB in the host app and run `require 'my_other_gem'`, I get this error

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_other_gem`

When I'm playing in the my_other_gem directory and I spin up IRB, the same `require 'my_other_gem'` command does not error out.  Everything runs normally.  But for some reason I can't require my_other_gem when I'm in my host gem.

What step am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `bundle install` on your host app? Does it find `my_other_gem` properly?

Comment: Also you probably have a typo on the Gemfile, it should be `gem 'my_other_gem' path: '../my_other_gem', require: 'my_other_gem'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the typo.  I added the missing colon in my post.

Comment: When I run `bundle install`, it finds the gem.  I see the normal output: `Using my_other_gem (0.0.1) from source at ../my_other_gem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you start `irb`? You need to run it in the bundler context with `bundle exec`.

I just tried and if I just run `irb`, I get the same error.
But if I run `bundle exec irb`, it works.

Comment: Yep. That's it.  I was just being sloppy.  Should have run it with bundle exec.  Thanks for your help!